# How to replace hidden nodes by "virtual" edges?

Tags: filter, gephi

Take a simple network `A=B=C`, where node `B` has the attribute `minor`. When I just filter out that attribute, I'll get the graph `A   C`. However, I want a visualisation of the fact that `A` and `C` are indirectly connected, i.e. `A---C`. How can this be achieved? Are filters even the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but I don't think this is something you can achieve without processing your data first, looping through all the edges that involve B, creating an array of B's neighbours and then creating new edges linking them.

The exact way to do this depends on the format of your data and the programming language.

You could also add edges manually in Gephi, but that is of course only realistic for small graphs.

I don't think filters are the right tool for this because they simply exclude nodes (and edges) but don't create new ones. https://github.com/gephi/gephi/wiki/Filter

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I've come to the same conclusion. I'd probably have to write a plugin for this, or try pre-0.9 subnodes which I've barely read about...